# Use 230V 50Hz electronics in U.S.A

Tags: usa, europe, power

I want to visit friends in U.S.A. and may stay there for maybe a month. I would like to bring my electronics with me and need to know how I could use them in America. They use 230 V, 50 Hz (I am from Germany).

I think America uses 120 V, 60 Hz (a friend told me).

I have seen travel adaptors however I fear putting 120V, 60Hz into my electronics (most don't do 120 V/60 Hz) and then breaking them.

Comment: You need to carefully look at the labels for each thing. Most newer portable electronic things are designed to work over the full range of AC voltages and frequencies. They don't need a transformer, only a plug adaptor.

Comment: It really depends on what ‘devices’ are. You showed a picture of a PSX in a comment – that internally runs on some low DC current as far as I am aware but it may or may not have an external PSU. Powering e.g. a SNES is no problem, just use a corresponding US-built PSU because they also scrunch down. The VCR you also mentioned may be more complex to determine/accomodate as most VCRs I’ve seen only have a fixed cord/plug.

Comment: @Jan the PSX is a case where the PSU is built in, only an AC plug is required to power the machine (no external pack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is likely a "kill a housefly with a grenade" solution, I ended up buying a secondhand [GoHz 500VA frequency/voltage converter](http://www.gohz.com/500va-frequency-converter). As I also digitize VHS tapes from around the globe, I need VCRs from different countries, too. Since tapes are sensitive to differing speeds, frequency is important. I now use this unit not only when traveling to U.S.A. but with foreign VCRs that cannot use 230V/50Hz.

You could probably build a similar one yourself as long as you're careful and you know what you're doing. Brand new these GoHz units are expensive--I would recommend finding one used like I did. Don't spend your money just yet, look around and you might find a good deal!

If you're just a regular consumer, check your devices, they may already support foreign voltages/frequencies. If they have separate transformer packs like the Nintendo Wii, buy one for your destination/home country. (That's how I also use USA Wii in Germany, I use it with a EUR transformer pack.)

**Read update below regarding input voltages**

---

I forgot to clarify a bit further. The GoHz unit I purchased above supports 230VAC input at either 50 or 60Hz. Since the unit allows for either of the common household frequencies, I would also have to bring a voltage step-up converter with me to the states (to step up 120V to 230V) to use it.

I haven't been to the U.S.A. since I have purchased this device, because of the ongoing virus problems, so I have been unable to confirm its operation successful outside of Germany. However I *can* confirm it at least works the other way around (as noted earlier, I have VCRs from U.S.A. working properly here). I assume everything *should work* as expected if/when I can visit U.S.A. again. I will update this post with my results when I am able to test this.

Comment: Out of interest that page says the input voltage is "factory selected", can the input voltage be relatively easilly changed when travelling or do you have to use a transformer to supply your frequency converter in some places?

Comment: @PeterGreen Very good question, I forgot to add that detail to my original post. It has been edited to explain further.

Answer (score 14):

You need to check the label on each device and see what voltage and frequency can be used on them.

Many electronic power supplies will be "universal" and will work from 100 V to 240 V, 50 or 60 Hz.

- If the device is universal then you only need an adapter for the plug.
- If the device is 230 V only but will accept 50 or 60 Hz then you need a 120 to 230 V transformer with an adequate VA rating for all the devices you have.
- If the device is 50 Hz only (unlikely) then it's going to be more trouble than it is worth to convert.

Comment: Hello, the majority of my devices are 220-240v/50hz only. Only a few (macbook charger) do allow 100-240 50/60

Comment: Example: http://www.the-liberator.net/site-files/retro-games/hardware/Sony-Playstation/sony-playstation-scph-7502-ps1-pal/sony-playstation-scph-7502-ps1-pal-05-bottom.JPG

Comment: @leetbacoon "the majority of my devices are 220-240v/50hz only" please read the owners manual very carefully about that. There are very few devices restricted to 50 Hz only. Japan has two power grids, in one area there is 50 Hz, in the other area 60 Hz. So electronics build in Japan are designed to work both with 50 and 60 Hz.

Comment: Typically the only devices which will be sensitive to 50 and not 60Hz are devices containing synchronous motors.

Comment: Or cheap clocks that use the line frequency for time keeping.

Comment: @JRE Oh yes, clocks based on line frequency are always fun. They run slightly faster or slower depending on where you are on the grid.

Comment: Don't bring 50 Hz devices to the US. You won't be able to power them. I am skeptical that the playstation really is 50 Hz only, but it is clearly labelled that way. You can try powering it with a small step-up transformer in the US, but if you don't want to take the risk, then leave it at home. I think that is an older device. Maybe 20 years old?

Comment: Hair dryer, supposedly, will simply not heat up properly since it is not getting enough to 'eat' or something that boils water takes longer. Damage is less likely as a general rule. A US device could blow if the device cannot deal with the extra voltage recieved with 230 V.

Answer (score 2):

You need a step-up 120:230 transformer with a suitable VA rating to cover all the devices you have that are not rated for universal mains input.  Computers, phone chargers etc typically are rated for 100 to 230V so they can be used world wide for example.

The mains frequency should not be an issue as very few devices rely on it for timing though I do have a clock that does.

Most builders merchants will stock suitable transformers but you may find it easier to obtain in the US.  My local merchant in the UK only stocks 1:1 and step-down transformers since few people in the UK have access to a 110/120V volt supply though they may have equipment requiring the lower voltage.  I'm sure you could order a step-up transformer in Germany but it is unlikely to be a stock item.

Comment: The OP needs a step-UP transformer to operate his 240 V-only devices on 120 V.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Now corrected

Answer (score 1):

As long as non of your electronics have an ac motor in them (very unlikely) the frequency does not matter. You just need to step up the voltage.

The cheapest way to to do that is to use an autotransformer. This needs to be rated for the power that your electronics take

Your friend may be able to get you one before you arrive They are probably cheaper in the US and they can be heavy. You probably do not want to include it in your luggage.

Comment: International flights tend to allow 1-2 pretty heavy heavy checked bags. Weight might not be an issue.

Comment: One example is a vcr (still use one :) ). Some parts are motors (eject tape).

Comment: Your VCR is probably using PAL video. North America uses NTSC so it might be useless.

Comment: @Transistor Oh my friend's TV uses both PAL/NTSC, I checked

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it seems you are planning on bringing some devices which are quite old (playstation) and in some cases, not the usual portable devices (VCR) and which are labelled for 50 Hz only. Nobody can guarantee you that they will work correctly.

It will be quite difficult to have 50 Hz power in the US. Your best bet would be to bring an inverter from Germany with you. You can buy a 12V power supply that runs on 120VAC at 60 Hz, and run the inverter from the power supply.

It is possible that some electronics labelled for 50 Hz will work at 60 Hz, but nobody can 100% guarantee this, and given the nature of your devices, which are now irreplaceable and could be museum pieces, I suspect you don't want to take any risk.

Comment: The problem with going 120V/60Hz -> 12VDC -> 230V/50Hz is that you'll be putting a *lot* of amps through the 12-volt part of the system.

Comment: True. It will be like 25x the 230V amps. So if the device uses 1A at 230, then it will require roughly 25A at 12V. Not trying to provide exact numbers. But as long as the devices are under 300 Watts or so, and used one at a time, it should be manageable with 8 or 10AWG wire in the 12V section. Call it 2.5mm to 3.5mm diameter wire. VCR and playstation will likely be under 300 Watts. TV not, but I doubt the OP is bringing a TV from Germany.

Comment: Basically, I think the OP needs to leave these devices at home. But if it is critical to run them in the US and tolerance for risk is very low, an inverter is still the best solution, I believe. Variable AC power supplies exist. In fact I have one, but it seems not practical for the OP's purpose. Very large and heavy.

Comment: Or the OP could buy a purpose-built travel adapter that does both voltage and frequency conversion rather than cobbling one together from parts not meant to do that job.  Typically, these devices do the frequency conversion at high voltage, not low voltage, to keep the amperage (and cost) down.

Comment: Hey, @Mark,  I am happy to delete my answer if you can show me one that looks plausible.

Comment: It took a bit of hunting on Amazon, but I finally found one that is A) capable of turning 115V/60Hz into 230V/50Hz, B) claims UL certification, and C) doesn't make outrageous claims about wattage: https://www.amazon.com/VZolution-Transformer-Appliance-Re-settable-Protection/dp/B07PGJYDWS

Comment: @Mark that price is way more appealing than this one i found earlier: https://www.amazon.com/GoHz-Frequency-Converter-Step-down-Step-up/dp/B01GH5SWH4

Comment: @Mark I believe that is just a transformer. It mentions that it is automatically compatible with 50/60 Hz, but it nowhere says it converts between 50 and 60 Hz. I could be wrong, but that is my take on it. That GoHz thing is more like what I have. A bench instrument that I have used in the past to test samples of small 220 and 240 AC-DC power adaptors.

Comment: Schaefer Power, a German company, seems to make frequency converters. OP could look into it. Webpage has no prices which, in my experience, means that it is expensive equipment.

Comment: @leetbacoon, the one you found is a heavy-duty laboratory-grade device: fully-adjustable voltage and frequency, true sine-wave output, 1kVA capacity.

Comment: @Mark  and mkeith, do you guys have experience with the Gohz one? It sounds most reliable to me, even though it might be expensive and also quite heavy lol

Comment: I have no experience.

Comment: @leetbacoon, no experience, but the specs say it's overkill for running ordinary household devices.  Mains power is only guaranteed to be within 10% of what the standard calls for, so you can use a much cheaper converter and still have everything work properly.